# Ajax post request is not working in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jquery, localhost

I just want to send data using ajax post request to a remote server. The following code works fine in IE but not in chrome. Why ? What is "Origin http//localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin"problem? How can i make it work in chrome also. Please help me.

```
 var http = new ajaxRequest();
        var url = "http://abcd.abc.com/login";
        var params = "username=name&password=pass&id=12345";
        http.open("POST", url, true);

        //Send the proper header information along with the request
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
        http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            //Call a function when the state changes.
            if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                window.alert(http.responseText);
            }
        }
        http.send(params);


  function ajaxRequest(){
     var activexmodes=["Msxml2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"] //activeX versions to check for in IE
     if (window.ActiveXObject){ //Test for support for ActiveXObject in IE first (as XMLHttpRequest in IE7 is broken)
      for (var i=0; i<activexmodes.length; i++){
       try{
        return new ActiveXObject(activexmodes[i])
       }
       catch(e){
        //suppress error
       }
      }
     }
     else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
      return new XMLHttpRequest()
     else
      return false
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not allowed to make AJAX requests to other servers. Your script must run on the same domain as the server you are making AJAX requests to, UNLESS that server allows you to do it with the aforementioned Access-Control-Allow-Origin.